# What's wrong with this apache setup?

Tags: apache, apache2, virtual-hosts

Below is my /etc/apache2/sites_available/default file.

I have pointed mysite.com to localhost in /etc/hosts and the website works fine when accessed from the same machine it's running on.

However, if I get a second machine, edit its /etc/hosts and point mysite.com to the first machine, then apache only serves up a generic `Not Found: The requested URL / was not found on this server` message. (I get the exact same message if I navigate to http://127.0.0.1 on the first machine instead of using the name mysite.com) Nothing is put into access.log or error.log but there is something in other_vhosts_access.log

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Also, when I kick Apache it says `NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`, in case that's relevant.

Here's the config file:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is in your `<VirtualHost mysite.com:80>`. I would try `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

If I recall correctly, that spot is supposed to be the IP the traffic is coming in on. I just know that I always use '*' or the static IP of the server in that spot when I configure my web servers.